# Can I delete my iOS app from iTunes and move customers to a different one?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect

We currently have an app that we release as several different apps for different brands in iTunes. The code is the same but they have different names, icons, artwork, etc.

For some reason marketing want to replace these three apps with a single app that has a different name again. I can see from this question [Apple iphone app transfer or app replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044359/apple-iphone-app-transfer-or-app-replacement) that I can use the original app id to push the new app, but what can I do for the other apps in the store? When you delete an app can you push a customer to a new app, or put up a message for them to install the new one? Or do I release a new version of the other apps that pops up a message telling them to install the new one?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already have some sort of news or messaging in place in your current app (I'm assuming you don't) you would indeed have to update the apps so that they display some sort of message directing your users to the new app. It's also common to put a notice in your old app descriptions and/or release notes.

Comment: That's it. Furthermore, in case you don't have a way to notify the users, it would be good to first create a new version of the apps with a link to the new app. And wait till (nearly all) the users have installed the new apps before asking them to move to the new one.