# delete my app from appstore & Upload it again from a different developer account. If yes, what changes are required to be made

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

I wanted to delete my app from my current developer account and re-upload it from a different developer account. Yes, i am aware of the fact that i have an option to TRANSFER the ownership of apps from one account to another. 
But what if i wish to go this way : 
DELETING FROM CURRENT ACCOUNT -> UPLOADING FROM DIFFERENT ACCOUNT

PLEASE REPLY ME FOR BOTH THE SCENARIOS - 
A. TRANSFERRING THE APP & UPLOADING A NEW VERSION FROM THE NEW ACCOUNT
B. AS DELETING AND UPLOADING A NEW BUILD OF THE SAME APP FROM THIS NEW ACCOUNT WITH SAME CERTIFICATES

I read on some links available online that i am required to change the bundleId in this case.

Comment: right. you need to change the bundleId of your app.

Comment: @AshokLondhe   
Actually we have two accounts under the same organisation and i need to transfer app from one account to other. What can be done in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.To transferring apps go-through this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH31-SW37)

2.To deleting app there are few restrictions is there.

Apps can’t be deleted if they are part of a `Game Center group, in an app bundle, or currently displayed on a store`. But you can remove from sale.

> But note it once you deleted or removed from sale.Then that deleted
> app name,SKU ID & bundle id can't be restored with in the same
> organization. So it clearly states you can't use same certificates too ofcourse you need to give new bundle id..etc.

For more go to [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH31-SW37)

Comment: Where can i find SKU of my app? Is there any way to change it?

Comment: Actually we have two accounts under the same organisation and i need to transfer app from one account to other. What can be done in this scenario?

Comment: in your new account change SKU & app name and build id too that's all.

Comment: Please refer to this link below : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044359/apple-iphone-app-transfer-or-app-replacement

My problem is similar to this one.

Comment: we need clear question to answer correctly, that link regarding app transfer but you said   But what if i wish to go this way : DELETING FROM CURRENT ACCOUNT -> UPLOADING FROM DIFFERENT ACCOUNT instead of TRANSFER the ownership of apps from one account to another.

Comment: Once transfer is done and i have the app in your itunes connect
Now can i add a new version of the App to itunes connect.
Is following criterion that is to be met :
Application Bundle Identifier is the same as with the App you're updating
Your new App is signed with a correct certifcate/provisioning profile (just correct for the appid, doesn't have to be the same one)
I would have to create new certificates of the other developer account (Since its a new one, just created it two days ago) & use those certificates in my app for uploading. Keeping the bundle id same both in app&certificates

Comment: please see the question again and the new comments as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DS Dharma You really helped alot. 
Can you please help me with transferring as well.? If i transfer the app to my other developer account (that falls in the same organisation) can I upload a new version of the app with the same bundle id? Also, ill be needing valid certifcates to upload it so i should create new certificates in the new account using team id and bundle id of the transferred app (the old ones) or i have to use the team id of the new devloper account. Hope I am clear enough!

Comment: @Akaanksha i m not yet transferred any apps but as of my knowledge you can't upload with same bundle id in different account(but may be organization level is possible plz check once).but  i m sure you can upload new version of app with same bundle id in same account(which you already distributed app in account).just change version & build number

Comment: Thankyou @DS Dharma. You indeed helped alot. I'll be tryin this will surely keep you updated.